# Rails 3 rendering partial with javascript from remote: true call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I have a `remote: true` call in my Rails 3 app controller `HotelsController`, which executes `show_map` action. Pretty simple.

```
<%= link_to "Map", show_hotel_map_path(@hotel.id), remote: true %>
<div id="hotel_map"></div>
```

`show_hotel_map` action is pretty basic

```
def show_hotel_map
  @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

`show_hotel_map.js.erb` is meant to render a partial `map` within JQuery-UI dialog with rendered Google Maps map

```
$("#hotel_map").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  position: 'center',
  resizable: false,
  title: "Map",
  open: function(){
      $("#hotel_map").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "map") %>")
  }
});
```

`_map.html.erb` partial does nothing but executes `render_map` helper

```
<%= render_map %>
```

`render_map` helper does all the stuff with rendering a map with `Gmaps4Rails` gem

```
module HotelsHelper

  def render_map
    if @hotel.address.latitude && @hotel.address.longitude
      map = @hotel.address.to_gmaps4rails
    else
      geo = Gmaps4rails.geocode("#{@hotel.continent.name}, #{@hotel.country.name}, #{@hotel.location.name}")[0]
      map = [{lat: geo[:lat], lng: geo[:lng]}].to_json
    end
    gmaps(:markers => { :data => map, :options => { :draggable => true } })
  end
end
```

The problem is that `Gmaps4Rails` gem renders some javascript for proper Google Maps handling, but apparently this javascript is being truncated by `escape_javascript` call from  `show_map.js.erb` view. So when I click `"Map"` link, JQuery-UI dialog is being rendered, but it does not have any payload, since no Javascript was executed. `render_map` helper works perfectly by itself, so I guess that's not a problem with `Gmaps4Rails` gem. Is there any workarounds so I can execute that javascript? I can think of few hacks, but maybe there is more Rail-ish way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to whom it may concern, I solved it using UJS technique described in Gmaps4Rails wiki

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Using-with-UJS

It is not very DRY but I guess there's not many other options.

Comment: the solution presented there is absurd, see my gist: https://gist.github.com/1643990